# Migration from Resources to Addressables is not safe?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets, addressables

In my project, I decide to migrate to `Addressables`. I used to use Resources to load my assets before. So that, I replaced all `Resources.LoadAsync` to `Addressables.LoadAssetAsync`. And I ran onto a case, when this replacement makes my application completely broken.

The case is next:

I have remote assets and update catalog on application start to fetch new bundles.
I have an asset in resources folder: `path/to/boss_icon`. And load it with `Addressables.LoadAssetAsync("path/to/boss_icon")`
In a time I had deleted this icon, cooked new application, cooked new Addressables build and uploaded it to my server.
After this, `path/to/boss_icon` becomes not available in **old** builds where it is physically included in build. As I get, this happens, because `path/to/boss_icon` is not presented in the new catalog. If it is, it makes Addressables completely unusable for managing local assets.

Is there a way to not make local assets unavailable on catalog updates, or I need to migrate back to `Resources`?

Comment: Just to clarify `path/to/boss_icon` is within a `Resources` folder? Or anywhere in your `Assets` ? In that case you might want to rather use `AssetReference`

Comment: It is in my Resource folder.

Comment: I don't think you can simply use a Resources path as path for `Addressables.LoadAssetAsync` .. your assets should all be in your addressables catalogue with a proper path instead - I still don't get the exact use case but since your assets were in Resources before and worked in older versions - and addresables are only in the new version I don't really see why old versions should be affected by this migration

Comment: @derHugo by older version I mean the older version, but already after migrating to Addressables.

Comment: but well apparently you are not fully migrated yet then if your assets are still not correctly in your addressables catalogue .. or maybe I'm getting this wrong here

Comment: All my resources assets are added to the catalogue. The problem is, when I update this catalog with `Addressables.UpdateCatalogs`, I lose ability to use some of my local assets, because they could be removed from the catalogue in latest application version, but still be used in the version, installed on user device.